# Tool for automated validation of web-page against formatting/layout rules?

Tags: javascript, validation, layout, coding-style

Im a UI developer on a financial website and been tasked with finding (or creating) a tool to automate testing pages against a bunch of formatting/layout rules

Example rules;

- use of bracket format for numbers: (123) rather than -123
- use of ISO codes for financial amounts: USD 123 rather than $123
- all numbers should be right justified
- checking of format and case of various text labels
- (nice to have) checking of specified padding widths between certain elements
- (nice to have) image comparison against known good screenshots

Also - the tool will need to be usable on a non public version of the site (i.e. for internal pre-prod testing)

Is anyone aware of any tools for doing this kind of thing? Ive googled around but couldn't find anything even remotely close. I *could* create a bespoke tool to do this but Id much rather not reinvent the wheel if I can help it!

Cheers!

Comment: To give some more info - I investigated this a bit further the other day but still haven't been able to find any existing tools that do what we want. I was initially thinking of creating a javascript solution (in the theme of jsUnit) but in our case, our back end is developed in c#/visual studio. Hence, a c# solution using the Web Test framework (our testers already use it) is looking like a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I adapted a validation engine called mobileOk checker, that performs some [validations](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobileOK-basic10-tests/) to make sure a web page is mobile friendly, but can be easily extended to include your own tests.

Tests can be implemented in Java or using XSL.  For example [this test](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/2007/mobileok-ref/src/org/w3c/mwi/mobileok/basic/xslt/PopUpsTest.xsl?rev=1.8&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) (under /src/org/w3c/mwi/mobileok/basic/xslt) checks whether a popup exists in the page or not.

In the "Documents" section of [this page](http://www.w3.org/2005/MWI/BPWG/Group/TaskForces/Checker/) you can access the sources.  I don't know its current state, but it is opensource.  If you don't find anything better, it could be a starting point.  Maybe it is harder to take a look at how it works than implementing it by yourself...

Comment: Thanks for the info - some interesting stuff there

Comment: Well - I gave it a week no other answers so I guess that makes you the winner. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry you didn't get any better or more precise answer.  It would be great if you finally share the solution you choose.